# Return list of json objects from generic handler

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm making ajax request to generic handler to get the list of json strings.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyHandler.ashx",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "text/plain",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (jsonList) { 
                var myArray = new Arrary();
                myArray = jsonList;
                var jsonObject1 = JSON.parse(myArray[0]);
            }
```

**MyHandler.ashx**

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    List<string> allstrings = new List<string>();

    allstrings = (List<string>)context.Application["allstrings"];
    context.Response.Write(allstrings);
}
```

I'm not sure about content type & data type to be used here. The request never reach to success function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: {},
            url: "MyHandler.ashx",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (jsonList) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(jsonList));
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("Error" +JSON.stringify(e));
            }
        });
```